# Power query: lookup minimum date if criteria fulfilled

Tags: excel, if-statement, lookup, minimum, powerquery

Let's say I have two columns: **ID** and **date**. I want to add a third column **Earliest Date**. This column should look up the earliest or minimum **date** across all the data that matches the **ID** in that row. It would produce the below - see **ID 501**. I have a lot of data so need to use power query. How do I write the formula?

```
ID  Date    Earliest Date
501 01/01/2017  01/08/2015
203 08/06/2015  08/06/2015
304 01/04/2014  01/04/2014
501 01/01/2016  01/08/2015
201 01/02/2015  01/02/2015
501 01/08/2015  01/08/2015
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the ID columns, you can also do a Group By on ID with the All Rows aggregate and an aggregate for the minimum date in the Date column. The builder should look like the picture below:

[image: Group by builder]

You'll get another column called Rows which contains the original table. If you expand this column to display the Date column, you'll get the table you want.

[image: Expand the rows column]

Comment: If you want to preserve each row of the original, you'll need to Join it against the original table. If you only want the earliest row for each date, then this is the best.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to join the original data with itself, using a minimum aggregation to calculate Earliest Date.

---

From this starting data in a Query called `Query1`:

```
ID,Date
501,01/01/2017
203,08/06/2015
304,01/04/2014
501,01/01/2016
201,01/02/2015
501,01/08/2015
```

Join the data with: Combine > Merge Queries (aka "Join") >  Merge Queries as New (to avoid modifying Query1)

Pick `Query1` ID column each time, and leave the default Left Outer join Kind:
[image: Join]

Next, choose Transform > Structured Column > Aggregate, and pick "Count of Date" (It would be better if the UI suggested a minimum aggregation, but we can fix that by touching the code directly).

Next, turn on the Formula Bar (View > Layout > Formula Bar) and edit the formula to replace `List.Count` with `List.Min`. Rename the new column, and you're done!

---

My full "M" formulas:

Query1:

```
let
    Source = Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document("ID,Date
501,01/01/2017
203,08/06/2015
304,01/04/2014
501,01/01/2016
201,01/02/2015
501,01/08/2015"))
in
    Source
```

Merge1:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Query1,{"ID"},Query1,{"ID"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Aggregated NewColumn" = Table.AggregateTableColumn(Source, "NewColumn", {{"Date", List.Min, "Earliest Date"}})
in
    #"Aggregated NewColumn"
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I tried this, but with over 2 million rows of data, after 2hrs this still wasn't done :(

Answer (score 1):

For each row you get the earliest date by filtering source table by thisrow[ID], and then selecting minimum from [Date] column of the resulting table.

```
let
    Source = #table(type table[ID=Int64.Type, Date=date], {
    {501,"01/01/2017"},
    {203,"08/06/2015"},
    {304,"01/04/2014"},
    {501,"01/01/2016"},
    {201,"01/02/2015"},
    {501,"01/08/2015"}
    }),
    Convert = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),

    AddMinDateColumn = Table.AddColumn(Convert, "Earliest Date", (thisrow) => List.Min(Table.SelectRows(Convert, each [ID] = thisrow[ID])[Date]), type date)
in
    AddMinDateColumn
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain what the arrow function is doing here please? I understand the logic, i.e. retrieving the current row value, but not the syntax. Thanks.

Comment: @deethreenovice It defines a function within expression. 
For example, when you see `each` in function, this parameter accepts another function. Instead of `each` you may define a variable and then write a nested function(s) which are executed for each item processed. Instead of `each _` you can write `(x) => x`.  
Here for every row, which is defined as `thisrow` few nested functions are executed: `Table.SelectRows()` is used to return a table with `[ID] = thisrow[ID]`, and then `[Date]` used to get a list of dates out of it. Then `List.Min` extracts minimum date.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @deethreenovice you can see the both examples in this line. I had to use `thisrow`, as `each` keyword may only be used once. Expression `Table.SelectRows(Convert, each [ID] = thisrow[ID])` already uses `each`, so if you write `each [ID] = _[ID]` this will return all rows of the table, as every row's ID is compared to itself (`_[ID]`). This may also be expressed as `Table.SelectRows(Convert, (processedRow) => processedRow[ID] = thisrow[ID])`

Comment: thank you - think I am just about there. So when using a function that accepts another function as a parameter (e.g. TableAddColumn), you declare that function with `each` or `(x)=>` and it's implicit that the current row is passed to it as a parameter? And thus you can access items from the row with `[columnName]` or `x[columnName]`?

Comment: @deethreenovice you should use `_[columnName]` with `each` keyword. Also, it is not current *row*, it is current *item*, depending on function. For list functions a list item is passed there, for example.